# updating a paired list in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am trying to update a list consisting of pair values as:

```
list = [('n1',1),('n2',2),('n3',3),('n4',4),('n5',5)]
```

Now I want to update the value with n1 to 16. So I tried t make like this:

```
>>> list['n1'] = 16
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

What is the way to access the list using the key value kind of functionality?

Comment: You're looking for `dict`, otherwise loop over and update based on matched item.

Comment: But I want to access the list only

Comment: I tried with `dict` but my rest module needs that value as `list` and not `dict`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
>>> lst = [('n1', 1), ('n2', 2), ('n3', 3), ('n4', 4), ('n5', 5)]
>>> lst = [('n1', 16) if 'n1' in item else item for item in lst]
>>> lst
[('n1', 16), ('n2', 2), ('n3', 3), ('n4', 4), ('n5', 5)]
```

Comment: What happen? The previous comprehension was quite good I guess.

Comment: @Jaffer: it's the same, just in the form of an interactive shell demo..

Comment: Can you please add the previous comprehension?

Comment: and I don't know the index

Answer (score 3):

Convert it to a `dict`

```
myList = [('n1',1),('n2',2),('n3',3),('n4',4),('n5',5)]
myDict = dict(myList)
myDict['n1'] = 16
```

also, it's not recommended to use `list` as a variable name, because it's the name of a [built-in function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-list) in python.

Answer (score 1):

Use `dict`

> > > dict(mapping) -> new dictionary initialized from a mapping object's
> > >           (key, value) pairs

```
d = dict(list)
d['n1'] = 16
```

Note** Don't use `list` as variable name it will override the inbuilt function `list`.

Answer (score 1):

You can access items in a list by their location, not by their values.

**If this kind of an update is done often, you probably want to use a *[dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html) (scroll to 5.5)*.
A dictionary stored data in a key-value format, such that you can access and update values by their keys.**

You can create one as such:

`some_dict = dict()`

Then, add the key-value pairs you want to store, like so:

`some_dict['n1'] = 1`

Then, if you would like to update the value stored by 'n1', just use the previous statement in a similar manner:

`some_dict['n1'] = "new_value"`

Answer (score 1):

You can not map list to key value pair. List can only be sliced.

You are lucky that you have list having key, value pair as tuples.

You can convert the same using dict(mapping) as other have answered.

```
my_list = [('n1',1),('n2',2),('n3',3),('n4',4),('n5',5)]
my_dict = dict(myList)
my_dict ['n1'] = 16
```